# is this right approach to use "string".replace('find','replace'); directly in JS?

Tags: javascript, string

Is this right to use:

'string'.replace('find','replace');

VS

stringVariable.replace('find','replace');

I am trying to save a variable and use string directly.

But, I am not sure if this is the right way. I hope anybody can help?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do that. In both cases you're still calling the `.replace` method on String.

Comment: Ok, I am not able to test my code on windows + IE, so I hope this will work everywhere. 

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Will this work? Yes

Is it ever *wise* to use a magic string? No (or not that I've ever seen at least)

What is the reason for wanting to "save a variable"?

My recommendation would be to use the variable...

Comment: True, I have also never seen. It is just to save a variable and finish code in single line. Thanks!